SA Bundling(Field Service Lightning)
We're currently utilizing FSL to create work orders and service appointments. Presently, our focus is on bundling multiple service appointments in a unified manner. However, we've encountered some issues when attempting to bundle, as illustrated by the following example:
SA 1: Start Date = 02/04/2024, Due Date = 10/04/2024
SA 2: Start Date = 02/04/2024, Due Date = 05/04/2024
These service appointments cannot be bundled because of differing due dates. Our objective is to bundle appointments based on due date availability. As we handle various types of service appointments with differing due dates, we are seeking a solution to address this challenge.
Your guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

In our organization, the due date field was a limitation (also for scheduling policies) because, even after surpassing the due date, we wanted to attend appointments. You can have a flow that adapts your due date to a fixed long-term value and use a custom field to determine the deadline for your service appointment. This way, the due date will not be a limitation for bundling
